# Mapear Array de Objetos e criar array novo a partir de chaves

Tags: javascript, array

Possuo um array chamado `originalArray`, esse array possui dois campos, grupo e conteúdo, grupo é uma string e conteúdo um objeto qualquer.

Basicamente quero dividir esse novo objeto em um numero desconhecido de campos, baseado na quantidade de grupos diferente, o grupo passará a ser a chave do campo de nosso novo objeto. O problema é que temos sempre que checar se a chave já existe (isso é normal?).

Cheguei ao seguinte código para resolver o problema, será que existe alguma solução melhor ou mais fácil, usando map ou alguma coisa do tipo?

```
const originalArray = [
  {group: 'ONE', content: {'a': 'b'}},
  {group: 'ONE', content: {'b': 'c'}},
  {group: 'TWO', content: {'c': 'd'}},
];
const newArray = {};
originalArray.forEach(value => {
  const { group, content } = value;
  if (newArray[group] === undefined) newArray[group] = [content];
  else {
      newArray[group].push(content);
  }
});
```

Entrada:

```
[ {group: 'ONE', content: {'a': 'b'}}, {group: 'ONE', content: {'b': 'c'}}, {group: 'TWO', content: {'c': 'd'}}]
```

Saída esperada:

```
{ ONE: [ { a: 'b' }, { b: 'c' } ], TWO: [ { c: 'd' } ] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há nada de errado com a sua solução, ela é simples e clara.

Você não pode utilizar o `map`, uma vez que esse método *mapeia* um *array* em um outro *array*. Desse modo, uma outra opção é utilizar o [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Algo assim:

```js
const originalArray = [
  { group: 'ONE', content: { a: 'b' } },
  { group: 'ONE', content: { b: 'c' } },
  { group: 'TWO', content: { c: 'd' } }
];

const newObject = originalArray.reduce((acc, current) => {
  const { group, content } = current;
  
  if (!acc[group]) {
    acc[group] = [content];
  } else {
    acc[group].push(content);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newObject);
```

Não há nada de errado com um `for`, `for..of`, `forEach` ou `reduce`, todos irão fazer a mesma coisa. Vai de preferência pessoal. Só tome cuidado que às vezes o `reduce` pode ser menos familiar para iniciantes e tornar a compreensão do código mais difícil.

Comment: Vou deixar esse link  aqui: https://medium.com/@JeffLombardJr/understanding-foreach-map-filter-and-find-in-javascript-f91da93b9f2c com mais infos de map, reduce, filter e semelhantes